# NGinx reverse proxy for websocket connections

Tags: nginx

I have a console app that runs on a few machines.  I can access it using a websocket client by entering the URL `ws://192.168.1.152/h264/`.  I need to be able to establish connections to these machines externally.  I have tried many options in Nginx.  I would like to be able to connect to `ws://streams.mydomain.com/101` and have it go to the IP above.  Here is a table of examples.

`ws://streams.mydomain.com/152/` > `ws://192.168.1.152`

`ws://streams.mydomain.com/153/` > `ws://192.168.1.153`

`ws://streams.mydomain.com/154/` > `ws://192.168.1.154`

I have tried various options including the following:

**Method 1**

```
http {
    server {
        listen      *;
        server_name streams.mydomain.com;
        location /101/ {
            proxy_pass $scheme://192.168.1.52;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        }
    }
}
```

This method results in "Invalid response" (gets a 301 and expects a 101)

**Method 2**

```
http {
    server {
        listen      *;
        server_name streams.mydomain.com;
        location /101/ {
            add_header  'Connection'    'Upgrade';
            add_header  'Upgrade'       websocket;
            return      101             $scheme://192.168.1.52;
        }
    }
}
```

This results in "Missing upgrade header".

**Other methods**

I also tried using the `stream` directive with no luck as well as `rewrite` under HTTP, also with varying success.

---

I posted a [question about the second method specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54970674/error-during-websocket-handshake-upgrade-header-is-missing), but I'm hoping that this question will open up answers for methods I haven't been able to find.

---

Here is a pastebin of the FULL config: https://pastebin.com/1H49n5LB

Comment: Method 2 just isn't going to work anyway so there's no point in pursuing that. What you want to do is track down the source of the 301 redirect. My guess is you haven't actually shared the entire nginx configuration with us, and something else that you haven't posted is causing it.

Comment: Added link to full config: https://pastebin.com/1H49n5LB

Comment: And for what it's worth, I have this temporarily working by creating subdomains for each "stream" (stream52.mydomain.com > 192.168.1.52) but I don't want to have to maintain all this on my external DNS, so `streams.mydomain.com/52/` would be preferred if at all possible.

Comment: I also encountered the same problem while trying to rewrite header by `proxy_set_header` in `stream` proxy.